# Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that $A$ is a Borel set, where: $$A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 |0<x\le1,0<y^2+z^2\le x\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$$
I know that we define the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets (lets call them O) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - in this case $\mathbb{R}^3$ - and that the members of this Borel $\sigma$-algebra are called Borel sets.
I also know some different properties of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, but I don't really know where to start.

Comment: To start: show $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 |y^2+z^2\le x\}$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to tackle this problem is to try to express this set as (countable) unions and intersections of (simpler) Borel sets. For example,

$A = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | 0<x\leq 1\,\}\cap \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | 0<y^2+z^2\leq x\,\}$

and we can try to show that each of them is a Borel set.

Another useful tool to tackle these kind of problems is to use measurable functions $f:(X, \mathcal{F})\to (Y, \mathcal{G})$. For these functions, we will have that $f^{-1}(C)$ will be a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable set for every $\mathcal{G}$-measurable set $C$. It turns out that continuous functions $f:(\mathbb{R^d}, \beta(\mathbb{R^d}))\to (\mathbb{R}, \beta(\mathbb{R}))$ will be in particular measurable functions, so one can deduce that some sets are Borel from the fact that they are the pre-image of a measurable function. For example, the unit ball is Borel because $f(x,y,z)=x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is a continuous function and then $f^{-1}([0,1))$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ since $[0,1)$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$.
Recall that open intervals, closed intervals, and intervals in general, countable unions of intervals, open sets, closed sets, compact sets, G-$\delta$ sets and F-$\sigma$ sets are many examples of sets that live in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over the reals, so there will be many (other) sets that can be expressed as the pre-image of an adequate Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ by an adequate continuous (or, of course, a more general Borel-measurable) function.

Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Think about what this set is. If you look at the boundary, you'll see you have the points satisfying $x=y^2+z^2$ as part of it, which is the weird cone like thing that you might remember from the multivariates of the calculus.

Given this, you could visually see that $C = \{(x,y,z): 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y^2 + z^2 = x\}$ is closed (which you still must prove rigorously). Also note $A = C \setminus \{(x,0,0) : 0\leq x \leq 1\}$. Since $C$ is closed, and the complement of the line is open, so the intersection is a Borel set (closed sets and open sets are Borel, so their intersection must be)

Answer (score 1):

Your set $A$ is the intersection of the open set $\{(x,y,z):0<x\text{ and }0<y^2+z^2\}$ and the closed (i.e., complement of open) set $\{(x,y,z):x\leq1\text{ and }y^2+z^2\leq x\}$.